# How to deselect already selected JRadioButton by clicking on it

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

Let's say we are having  some `JRadioButton`s which belongs to same `ButtonGroup`, when user clicks on a `JRadioButton` it got selected. I want to add a feature that when user click on already selected `JRadioButton`, it gets deselected, that is whole `ButtonGroup` will have no `JRadioButton` selected. 
I already searched which leads me [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2408689/230513) to use, `ButtonGroup` method, clearSelection. but problem is that when user clicks on already selected JRadioButton, it is not generating any `ItemStateChangeEvent`, which is generating by clicking on other unselected `JRadioButton`s.

Comment: Guess: your not 'supposed' to deselect a radiobutton, for that purpose use a checkbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Unselecting RadioButtons in Java Swing*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2408689/230513). As clicking is unavailable, please edit your question to indicate what _other_ user gesture(s) you have considered.

Comment: Let me clear this for you, if a buttonGroup has suppose 4 JRadioButtons, out of which 3rd JRadioButton is already selected one. Then again clicking on 3rd JRadioButton. It should clear selection of 3rd JRadioButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, as an alternate approach, override `ButtonGroup#setSelected(...)`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2 {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
      p.add(makePanel("Default ButtonGroup", new ButtonGroup()));
      p.add(makePanel("Custom ButtonGroup", new ButtonGroup() {
          private ButtonModel prevModel;
          private boolean isAdjusting = false;
          @Override public void setSelected(ButtonModel m, boolean b) {
              if (isAdjusting) {
                  return;
              }
              if (m.equals(prevModel)) {
                  isAdjusting = true;
                  clearSelection();
                  isAdjusting = false;
              } else {
                  super.setSelected(m, b);
              }
              prevModel = getSelection();
          }
      }));
    return p;
  }
  private JComponent makePanel(String title, ButtonGroup g) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
    for (String s: Arrays.asList("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")) {
      AbstractButton r = new JRadioButton(s);
      //AbstractButton r = new JToggleButton(s);
      p.add(r);
      g.add(r);
    }
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new Test2().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Masterful! Tested with `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel` and the key binding & mouse listener suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37599961/230513).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the approach [cited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2408689/230513). Because a `JRadioButton` is a `JToggleButton`, a mouse gesture is possible but problematic. I'd use a `MouseListener` on the enclosing panel and [*Key Bindings*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) on the buttons as shown below. Click in the panel surrounding the buttons or press the <kbd>escape</kbd> key to clear the selection of all buttons in the `ButtonGroup`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37599961/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private static final String UNSELECT = "UNSELECT";

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 5));
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton r1 = create("One", group);
        JRadioButton r2 = create("Two", group);
        p.add(r1);
        p.add(r2);
        p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                group.clearSelection();
            }
        });
        f.add(p);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JRadioButton create(String name, ButtonGroup group) {
        JRadioButton b = new JRadioButton(name);
        group.add(b);
        b.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), UNSELECT);
        b.getActionMap().put(UNSELECT, new AbstractAction(UNSELECT) {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                group.clearSelection();
            }
        });
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```